# Why did my power system suddenly stop working?

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, boost, charger

I've created a wearable device with a power system that is replicated from the Adafruit Powerboost 1000. It contains a charger and booster chip. It worked for several days until the red LED that signals the battery is low on charge started blinking. Now even with a fully charged battery, the power system does not work. The most confusing part is that when a fully charged battery is connected, measuring the voltage on the terminals shows 0.4 volts when its suppose to be 3.7 volts. After connecting it to another circuit, it shows 3.7 volts so the battery is not faulty or low on charge. My thoughts are that either too much heat damaged one of the chips (needed to add heatsink on power inductor due to heat but actual board was still retaining considerable heat), or some surge in voltage occurred when the battery went below some threshold. BTW I'm not an electrical engineer, I'm a computer engineer so this stuff is not my strong suit.

Below I've included an image of the schematic and pcb design. Maybe there is an issue with either one. Thank you for any  help!

[image: Fig 1. Important portion of schematic is the lower left two chips which make up the power system]

**Fig 1. Important portion of schematic is the lower left two chips which make up the power system**

[image]

**Fig 2. This layer is the whole power system with an irrelevant microphone on the bottom left**

Comment: The voltage on the **battery** terminals measures 0.4v? Then your circuit probably has a short circuit and the battery has a built-in protection circuit which is stopping it from exploding. (Short-circuiting a lithium battery usually makes it explode)

Comment: I’d suggest getting a multimeter and making some measurements. Complex electrical systems are difficult to diagnose just by looking at them.

Comment: Could it be a short from a damaged chip?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  Start by measuring the resistance at where the battery would normally connect (with battery removed).  If you find a short (or very low resistance) start working your way upstream with the schematic as your guide, until you find the culprit.

Comment: My professor said the same thing but not entirely sure what that means by measuring resistance. I measured the connector for the battery and it measured around 10 MOhms but is that expected? When going upstream am I measuring the resistance across only one component or leaving one lead on ground and the other on component pins? Also wouldn't it be easier to use the short circuit beeper functionality (not sure what its formally called haha) of a multimeter?